# Android Q, WifiNetworkSpecifier loosing Wifi immediately after connection is established

Tags: android, android-10.0

```
  @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
public void openSystemDialogToConnectToWifi(String ssid, ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback callback) {
    WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder builder = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder();
    builder.setSsid(ssid);
    builder.setWpa2Passphrase("secret");


    WifiNetworkSpecifier wifiNetworkSpecifier = builder.build();

    NetworkRequest.Builder networkRequestBuilder = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
    networkRequestBuilder.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);
    networkRequestBuilder.addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_RESTRICTED);
    networkRequestBuilder.addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_TRUSTED);
    networkRequestBuilder.setNetworkSpecifier(wifiNetworkSpecifier);

    NetworkRequest networkRequest = networkRequestBuilder.build();
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    cm.requestNetwork(networkRequest, callback);
}
```

This is the code I use, to connect to a new Wifi from my App.
I get an Ip-Adress, the wifi Symbol is visible very briefly in the status bar.
In the next Moment, Wifi-Symbol is gone and the system Dialog is visible again, to connect to the wifi.

When I debug the Callback it is going through the methods in this Order:

1. onAvailable
2. onCapabilitiesChanged
3. onBlockedStatusChanged (blocked: false)
4. onCapabilitiesChanged
5. onLost

all methods do nothing (just call super.method())

Hardware: OnePLus 6 with Android Q

Comment: We're seeing something very similar with a OnePlus 7T. Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: No Solution found yet

Comment: did you get any solution?

Comment: Hey did you get any solution for this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connect to Wifi in Android Q programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63124728/connect-to-wifi-in-android-q-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

I have been tracking & researching this a lot. All my findings along with my current most optimal solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65327716/8407336)

But more specific to your question is the following info taken from the link

As stated [here by Google](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143549613#comment14), some OEM Roms are not 'holding on to the request' and therefore the connection is dropping instantly. OnePlus have fixed this problem in some of their later models but not all. This bug will continuously exist for certain phone models on certain Android builds, therefore a successful fallback (i.e. a manual connection with no network disruption) is required. No known workaround is available

- removeCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET) wont help keep the connection on a OnePlus as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60660236/android-q-wifi-connection-via-wifinetworkspecifier-lose-connection-immediately-a/64867314#64867314)
- setting the Bssid wont help keep the connection on a OnePlus as stated [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/170406306#comment5)
- google cannot help, they have stated it is out of their hands [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/170406306#comment4)
- OnePlus forum posts confirming it working for some models (but not all) after an update, see [here](https://forums.oneplus.com/threads/wifinetworkspecifier-immediately-drops-connection.1219734/), [here](https://forums.oneplus.com/threads/connectivitymanager-wifinetworkspecifier-fails-to-establish-wifi-connections.1289177/) & [here](https://forums.oneplus.com/threads/can-not-connect-to-a-hotspot-with-wifinetworkspecifier.1180889/)

Comment: You could improve your answer following this tutorial:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer
For instance, you could give more information instead of the link.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue before, later modified the "**NetworkRequest**" as below

```
WifiNetworkSpecifier specifier = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
    .setSsid(ssid)
    .setWpa2Passphrase(password)
    .build();
NetworkRequest networkRequest = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
        .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
        .removeCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
        .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_TRUSTED)
        .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_RESTRICTED)
        .removeCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_METERED)
        .removeCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_VPN)
        .removeCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_FOREGROUND)
        .removeCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_CONGESTED)
        .removeCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_SUSPENDED)
        .removeCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_ROAMING)
        .setNetworkSpecifier(specifier)
        .build();
```

I just removed few of the unwanted/default Network capabilities given in the "**onCapabilitiesChanged()**" callback. Now the wifi is not fluctuating and no fail over is happening.

Comment: I modified networkRequest as suggested above answer still its keeps disconnecting. any idea about this

Comment: Please check below link may help,

- https://forums.oneplus.com/threads/can-not-connect-to-a-hotspot-with-wifinetworkspecifier.1180889/
- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143549613

Comment: The link and the answer doesn't help. That issue still persists. Is there any work around?

Answer (score 0):

Created new issue, due to fact that older was closed https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/170406306

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Please write a comment instead.